# Jenkins - sshagent plugin doesn't work with Kubernetes plugin

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, jenkins-plugins, ssh-agent

Our env: Jenkins version: 2.138.3
Kubernetes plugin: 1.13.5
Sshagent plugin: 1.17

I have a job that runs OK on an AWS machine (use sshagent works as it should) but when I run the same job on our Kubernetes cluster it failed on ssh error.

Attached the working pipeline:

```
pipeline {
    agent {
      label 'deploy-test'
    }
    stages {
        stage('sshagent') {
            steps {
                script {
                    sshagent(['deploy_user']) {
                        sh 'ssh  -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no 99.99.999.99 ls'
                    }
                }
            }  
        }
    }
}
```

If I change the label to `label 'k8s-slave'`, it fails on:

```
+ ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no 99.99.999.99 ls
Warning: Permanently added '99.99.999.99' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Any idea?

just added my kubernetes configuration in Jenkins
[image]

[image]

Comment: What's your configuration for the Kubernetes plugin?

Comment: @Rico   just update the question with the plugin configuration